# How to assign variables in the inspector for a script on an instantiated object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good evening.

So I want to assign a text box to an instantiated object but how do I go about doing this via code and not manually. As hundreds of these prefabs could be instantiated I need to be able to assign the text box in the inspector via code at runtime (As in when they are created).

[image: The PD texbox on here]

Just to note: all these fields are assigned on the object that this prefab is a clone of, just for some reason the scripts copy over but the assigned values don't?

Let me know if you need to see any code but I think the question explains enough.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: All of those hundreds of prefabs will have access to textboxes. It is better to create some kind of intermediate class that will be responsible for changing textboxes values and the objects from prefab will inform the intermediate class about the need for changes.

Comment: `Just to note: all these fields are assigned on the object that this prefab is a clone of, just for some reason the scripts copy over but the assigned values don't?` You can't have scene references in a prefab .. you could nest the text boxes under your prefab so they are simply shipped along with the prefab and the prefab would already know the references?

Comment: @stazik I did try that but then I have to make a list of all the prefabs and they use a for loop to get an index of them and then change the PD value or whatever. It could work but it’s quite complex and processor intensive. Maybe there’s an easier way.

Comment: @derHugo I think this could work.

Comment: I’ll close this in a bit if I can get it working. Until then I’ll leave it open just in case somebody else can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/how-to-store-references-to-scene-objects-in-prefabs - This post answers my question. (It is a set of ways to assgn variabkes to prefabs in the inspector).

I thought I might as well repost it here as the answer is on a different forum.

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

bullet.GetComponent<BulletScript>().shooter = gameObject;
```

Seems to be the best way to do it, using GetComponent to decidd what script you want to assign something to and then assigning that part using .variable = whatever you want it to be.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)